# Can I change the colour of player nameplates?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a LOT of trouble reading the odd purple/blue colour that WoW uses for player nameplates. I have to be pretty much on top of someone to make them out, and even then I struggle, it's just not a colour I can read well.

I tried looking in the options to see if I had the ability to change this colour to something else, but I couldn't find this anywhere.

Is there any way I can change the colour? I'd not be opposed to a mod to change it if it came to that, but I'm new to WoW, so I don't know what's all possible. Ideally, I'd like to not have to deal with a modpack, as I find those incredibly overwhelming to try to deal with, as they often have WAY too many options and I struggle with finding what I want, I get upset, and I give up.

(If I can find a way to change other nameplates too, that would be excellent - I do find the lime green a little tricky, but the blue/purple is the absolute worst.)

Comment: Just in the open world or in dungeon/raid instances?

Comment: @dly Both, ideally, but open world if I can only have one.

Comment: As of patch 7.2 the name plates work only very limited in dungeons and raids, that's why I asked. It would make no sense recommending an addon that doesn't work in raids if you specifically wanted one for that purpose. :)

Comment: @dly I haven't been playing long, I'm only level 17 and unlikely to do any raids or dungeons any time soon, my main focus right now is the open world. :)

Comment: @edit: The default settings don't support changing that. You'll need an addon for this, like for example [Tidy Plates](https://wow.curseforge.com/projects/tidy-plates) if a complete UI overhaul is too much for you.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't played WoW for a long time, but when I played there used to be a ton of UI mods, which allowed you to configure the UI any way you wanted and I doubt that changed.

[Curseforge](https://wow.curseforge.com/addons) is a great source for those addons.

[WoW Interface](http://www.wowinterface.com/addons.php) is as well.

For your problem in particular one of those three might help:

[Kuinameplates](https://wow.curseforge.com/projects/kuinameplates)

[Nephilistnameplates](https://wow.curseforge.com/projects/nephilist-nameplates?gameCategorySlug=addons&projectID=95895)

[nPlates](https://wow.curseforge.com/projects/nplates-2-0?gameCategorySlug=addons&projectID=101700)

Answer (score 4):

I'd actually suggest [Elvui](https://www.tukui.org/download.php?ui=elvui), because you can adjust your complete interface with it and it has a great support.

In your particular case it could look like this:
[image]

You can enable or adjust:

- Class color
- Health bar
- Cast bar
- Character level
- and others

When you have it installed just type `/ec` and select *NamePlates*. There you can set the font face and size of several texts and other designs and select which ones you want to have customized (friendly players, enemy players, friendly npc, enemy npc, etc.) and even customize each of them separately (like displaying health bars, level, castbars,...).

PS: If you can't see them (regardless of the addon you're using) just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to toggle friendly nameplates.

---

**Basic tutorial**

I admit, this special setting is hidden pretty well. Here you go:

Disable class colors - they're on by default:
[image]

Change the color:
[image]

Result of this example:
[image]

Comment: I think for complete UI rehauls, @Ash has to explore all the options. There were already a dozen or so available back when I stopped playing in 2011 and in my guild we used 6-7 different ones, each player has their own preference for the UI layout and looks. So, I decided to give an aggregate site of many addons as well as a few addons, which specifically adress the nameplate problem (for the record: nplates is also part of a complete UI rehaul).

Comment: @Dulkan you don't have to explore them all at once. A clean installation is a good start, especially for newcomers or people new to UI addons. Set it up, play around, try your results,.. (or disable unwanted options) I've recommended Elvui to new players a lot (fresh guildies, friends, etc) because it's very newbie friendly due to the self-explanatory design and most of them love it. And you can install complete interfaces from other players either from the internet (downloads on curse or other resources) or they can even send it to you in-game.

Comment: Having installed this, I can't for the life of me figure out how I can actually change the colour of the nameplates from the purple colour I have issues with. :(

Comment: @Ash did you enable the nameplates? -> /ec - nameplates - friendly players - check the enable box. And make sure your wow has nameplates activated (ctrl + v toggles them)

Comment: I did, but i just want to change the colour and that's it and I can't figure out how to do just that

Comment: @Ash added some screenshots to the post. It was hidden pretty well.. :D

Comment: Oh wow that's helpful, I will have to try this out when I play next.